# is it possible to break array like this?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a = array('2016-05-06', '2016-05-08', '2016-05-20', '2016-05-23');

foreach($a as $key => $value){
   $dateFrom = $value //2016-05-06 Then 2016-05-20
   $dateTo = $value //2016-05-08 Then 2016-05-23

   function range($dateFrom, $dateTo);
} //in the second loop get the others 2 like above
```

The point is to pass first and last date and make a range

in the end get an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-05-06
    [1] => 2016-05-07
    [2] => 2016-05-08
    [3] => 2016-05-20
    [4] => 2016-05-21
    [5] => 2016-05-22
    [6] => 2016-05-23
)
```

i got the first array with this, now the problem is being with the range using 4 dates

```
foreach(array_slice($dates, 2) as $key => $value){
     $a[] .= $datas[$key];

     if($key == 0){
         $a[] .= $value;
     } else {
         $a[] .= $value; 
     }
}
```

Comment: `is it possible to break array like this?` surely

Comment: I suppose, you need to write code which will read start date, end date and generate all intermediate dates, probably by increasing start date by 1 and comparing with end date

Comment: with code. yup, code will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this using [DatePeriods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php):

```
$ranges = array_chunk($dates, 2);          // Divide the array into groups of two

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');       // Define an interval of one day

foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    // Create DateTime objects for the start and end dates
    $start = new DateTime($range[0]);
    $end = new DateTime($range[1]);
    $end->add($interval);

    // Create a new DatePeriod object using the start and end DateTime objects
    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    // Iterate over the DatePeriod to fill your result array
    foreach ($period as $date) {
        $result[] = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

Comment: @EddieD. this is 10 times better than the one you accepted

Comment: @Dagon i've tested both and it worked i just picked the first, but now i got a problem with it, i gonna try this one

Answer (score 0):

Yes... it is possible and here is what i imagine you want:

```
            <?php
            $a                  = array('2016-05-06', '2016-05-08', '2016-05-20', '2016-05-23');
            $arrDuos            = array();

            $arrTempRange       = array();
            foreach($a as $intKey=>$dateVal){
                $arrTempRange[]     = $dateVal;
                if($intKey != 0 && $intKey%2){
                    $arrDuos[]      = $arrTempRange;
                    $arrTempRange   = array();
                }
            }

            $arrArrangedDate    = array();
            foreach($arrDuos as $intKey=>$arrDateRange){
                $startDate      = $arrDateRange[0];
                $endDate        = $arrDateRange[1];
                $dateDiff   = date_diff( date_create($endDate), date_create($startDate) )->days;
                for($i = 0; $i<=$dateDiff; $i++){
                    $incrementedDate    = strtotime($startDate) + (60*60*24*$i);
                    $arrArrangedDate[]  = date("Y-m-d", $incrementedDate); 
                }
            }

            // MANUALLY APPEND THE LAST ELEMENT OF THE ARRAY TO THE 
            // RESULTANT ARRAY IF THE ARRAY LENGTH IS ODD LIKE SO:    
            if(count($a)%2){
                $arrArrangedDate[] = end($a);
            }

            var_dump($arrArrangedDate);
```

Dumps:

```
       array (size=7)
          0 => string '2016-05-06' (length=10)
          1 => string '2016-05-07' (length=10)
          2 => string '2016-05-08' (length=10)
          3 => string '2016-05-20' (length=10)
          4 => string '2016-05-21' (length=10)
          5 => string '2016-05-22' (length=10)
          6 => string '2016-05-23' (length=10)
```

I hope this answers your question... ;-)

Comment: But there is also a caveat to this that is worth noting. ***If the length of your Input Array is odd (eg. 3, 5, 7, etc), the very last value will be truncated.*** However, i updated the code to handle that anomaly... Cheers @EddieD.

Comment: adding a day in seconds is really a **bad idea**, days are not all even. there are date classes you should use for this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: @Dagon How do you know the Date Classes themselves work internally? On a very lower level or higher level? In eons or in seconds & sub-divisions of a second? Maybe finding it out helps you understand whether there is a technical similarity or not. But i agree with you. Date Classes are Black-Boxes...which let you do things faster. But don't peek into the Black-Box because you may as well discover that **what is there is equally here...** the only difference being **perspective**... but nonetheless, **YOU ARE RIGHT** plus... his Dates have neither Hours, Minutes nor Seconds! **PEACE!**

Comment: i have read the source - you can to. it accommodates leap seconds. its not a black box its open-source. you just have to bother to read it.

Comment: @Dagon Then we agree to not disagree by not disagreeing in our agreement that we do agree... and thus: I know no more...